# How does a print/write statement access shared memory in an openmp parallel construct?

Tags: c++, fortran, openmp, shared

I am doing some exercises with openmp. The following program, proposed in two versions, deals with shared and private variables. I don't understand why the Fortran and C versions give different results (the C version giving the expected results). But I know that Fortran does the job correctly. If I store the values of variable `b` in an array, printing the results in the post-parallel region is in the right order. ). Do write/print in Fortran and printf in C, access the shared memory in the parallel region differently?

```
PROGRAM one
USE omp_lib

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: n_threads = 4
INTEGER :: id      
INTEGER :: a = -1
INTEGER :: b = 0

WRITE(*,'("Values in the serial region: "/,"a = ",I0, ", ", "b = ",I0)') a, b
WRITE(*,'("Values in the parallel region: ")')

!$OMP PARALLEL NUM_THREADS(n_threads) DEFAULT(none), PRIVATE(id, a), SHARED(b)
  id = omp_get_thread_num()
  a  = id + 1
  b  = id + 1
  WRITE(*,'("Thread rank ",I0," :" " a = ",I0, ",", " b = ",I0)') id, a, b 
!$OMP END PARALLEL

WRITE(*,'("Values in the serial region: "/,"a = ",I0, ",", " b = ",I0)') a, b

END PROGRAM one
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "omp.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = -1;
  int b = 0;
  int id;
  cout << "Values in the serial region: \n";
  printf("a = %d, b = %d \n", a, b); 
  //cout << "a = " << a << ", b =" << b << endl;
  cout << "Values in the serial region:" << endl;
  # pragma omp parallel default(none) private(id,a) shared(b)
  {
    id = omp_get_thread_num();
    a  = id + 1;
    b  = id + 1;
    printf("Thread rank %d: a = %d, b = %d \n", id, a, b);
  }
  cout << "Values in the serial region: \n"; 
  printf("a = %d, b = %d \n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

The output

```
latitude$ gfortran -fopenmp one.f90
latitude$ ./a.out
Values in the serial region: 
a = -1, b = 0
Values in the parallel region: 
Thread rank 0 : a = 1, b = 4
Thread rank 3 : a = 4, b = 4
Thread rank 1 : a = 2, b = 4
Thread rank 2 : a = 3, b = 4
Values in the serial region: 
a = -1, b = 4
latitude$ 
latitude$ g++ -fopenmp one.c
latitude$ ./a.out
Values in the serial region: 
a = -1, b = 0 
Values in the serial region:
Thread rank 0: a = 1, b = 1 
Thread rank 1: a = 2, b = 2 
Thread rank 2: a = 3, b = 3 
Thread rank 3: a = 4, b = 4 
Values in the serial region: 
a = -1, b = 4
```

[execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfbqg.png)

I want to know: Why, in the parallel region, the value of `b` is printed correctly in C and not in Fortran?

Comment: There is no locking in your program, so there are no guarantees on when b will be set relative to write/print.

Comment: Why do you make `b` shared if you want each thread to have distinct values of it? That is, can you explain what you think is happening with regards to private/shared and interaction with threads: it'll be much easier to explain what is happening if we know which misconception needs addressing.

Comment: (Note also that in Fortran more generally, a declaration like `integer :: b=0` means `b` has the SAVE attribute. In this case `b` already is saved - it's a variable in the main program - but if you do this in a subroutine, say, you can easily get exceptionally surprised, especially when using OpenMP.)

Comment: I am not familiar with fortran, but in the C code there is a race condition when accessing variable `b`, which is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior even can lead to correct result as well.

Comment: @francescalus "Why do you make b shared if you want each thread to have distinct values of it?" I suspect this is the point of the exercise - quoting the OP "The following program, proposed in two versions, deals with shared and private variables." I suspect he/she has been unlucky and the C++ version has given the output he/she incorrectly expects

Comment: @IanBush, absolutely. What I mean by my question is that while we can write a (long) answer explaining exactly what is happening in those parallel constructs detailing race conditions, locking, undefined behaviour, and the poor unfortunates who get to see the "right" answer and move on thinking all is well with the world, it's arguably more instructional for a student to explain why a particular (wrong) outcome is expected and have that corrected in a specific manner, than be subjected to a dissertation.

Comment: Please do not share images of your output, please use text and highlight it accordingly

Comment: In case it is not clear already - the race condition @Laci identifies in the C version of the code exists in the Fortran version too.  I can't speak to OP's statement *If I store the values of variable b in an array, printing the results in the post-parallel region is in the right order.* 'cos that code isn't shown.

Comment: Let me clarify my question. This code is just a beginner's code, to study race situations. I just want to know why in the parallel region, the value of b is printed correctly in c and not in fortran? 

Edit: I have included the output of the executables in the text

Comment: If you changed the fortran code in apppropriate places with  
"INTEGER b(n_threads)"   "b(a) = a"  "WRITE ... a,b(a)"  then your "SHARED(b)" would make sense. As to why the C version overcomes the race condition, I would only speculate that it could be all about timing of the thread interaction with printf.

Comment: @userXLII There is no point in discussing undefined behavior as it may vary among different machines and compilers.

Comment: I am aware that the only results that matter are those of the post-parallel region and that the value of b is unreliable and non-deterministic because of its shared status, the values of the parallel region are ultimately irrelevant. I am also aware that one does not place input/output operations in a region whose goal is speed. However, I am still curious about the performance of WRITE for gfortran, which always accesses the shared value very late, once all threads have finished, while PRINTF manages to access it while threads are working. Thanks to all.

Comment: *"WRITE for gfortran, which always accesses the shared value very late, once all threads have finished"* : this is a much too strong assumption, which should not be generalized to all codes. It's all the more difficult to draw any conclusion than the code here is simplistic, with a negligible workload inside the threads.